# What do people call the groups into which quantiles divide the population?

Tags: terminology, sample, quantiles, estimators

Is there a correct technical name for the group of observations between two quantiles? For example, if you have the values of the four cut-points that divide a population into five groups of equal size, my understanding is that these levels are the quintiles. However, there is often a reference to “quantile means” as the means of the subgroups of the total population when divided by the quantiles. My impression is that is not considered correct usage among statisticians, as the quantile means should refer to the mean value of the quantiles, across samples, say,  not to the groups of observations bracketed by them.  Is there a proper name for these groups?

I am interested in learning more about the statistical properties of the groups defined by the quantiles, rather than the quantiles themselves, and am having trouble finding even basic information – whether means for large populations will be approximately normal, how to estimate mean and variance when all you have is parameter estimates for the underlying distribution from which the sample is drawn, whether the sample means are unbiased estimators of the population means for these groups, construction of confidence intervals for means, etc. If I had a correct name for the groups, I think I should be able to find all these things rather quickly.

In addition, I would be grateful if anyone could point me toward their favorite entry to literature that addresses these questions.

Comment: Sometimes - though incorrectly - quantile-terms are used for the between-quantile groups. Thus you'll see expressions like "scored in the upper quartile" or a reference to income "in the [sixth decile](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22in+the+sixth+decile%22)" or similar expressions. This seems to be especially common with deciles. I'd be inclined to say "inter-quintile means" (but I wonder whether the not-strictly-correct "*intra*-quintile means" might not more often convey the correct impression).

Comment: The problem is, none of these terms -- nor any other terms that I have tried -- lead to any substantial literature on means for population subgroups bounded by quantiles. All I find are applied papers that take those means as primitive.

Comment: Maybe it's an opportunity to write some.

Comment: Dear Glen_b --If I were persuaded that this is not a well-explored topic I would consider writing something, but I think it is more likely that I just have not found the right search terms yet. Hence this question.

Comment: I don't think you need different technical terms here at all. First, using (e.g.) upper decile for the top 10% (i.e. an interval) is perhaps unfortunate, even incorrect, but any ambiguity is typically slight and in practice quickly resolved. Second, it is easy enough to use ordinary words such as bottom quarter, bottom tenth, top quarter, top tenth if any are needed. Third, often results are just given in tables and graphs and vocabulary need not be used at all. (As others do, I am presuming focus on English, but I suspect the point applies across languages.)

Comment: @NickCox: I agree with everything you say except your first sentence. Use any of the terms you have suggested, and try to figure out whether the mean for a decile group is an unbiased estimator of the true mean for that quantile group, or what its variance is, or whether there is a better estimator for the true mean than the sample mean, or how the ratio of two decile means is distributed, or anything along those lines. These terms lead in to the substantive literature, but they pick up little of the statistical literature than I am sure exists.

Comment: @andrewH: I guess our purposes are different here. I am focusing on how best to label things and whether terminology is inherently problematic. That was and is the question. I have no interest personally in the properties you mention, as in most problems I have seen dividing a range into quantile-based groups works mainly to degrade the information in the data. But people working with personal incomes, firm performance etc. seem to find such ideas useful. http://www.springer.com/statistics/social+sciences+%26+law/book/978-0-387-98778-1 may lead you to relevant literature.

Comment: @NickCox: You may find summary into quantile group means unhelpful, but unfortunately, in many cases that is the only way the data is published. For instance, if you want income distribution in the US as the census tract level, sample quintile means is all you can get. Many countries do this for subnational geographies.

Comment: @NickCox: The book you reccomend offers an excellent example of both your concern (problematic terminology) and my concern (no good search terms for statistical literature on quantile group means). On page 30 he discusses the 90/10 ratio, which is almost always calculated as a ratio of group means in the published literature. He then refers you for elaboration to ch. 13, which focuses entirely on quantile regression. Many of his references to empirical work use "deciles" or "quintiles" to mean the group means, but in discussing theory, he always means the break points.

Comment: You're free to suggest new terminology in this field.  (That book is by two authors, one female.)